# QGIS layout atlas or report : displaying 8 entities sheet on one sheet

Tags: qgis, layouts, atlas

I'm trying to make paper labels for material collected on field using qgis layout atlas.

I made my entity sheet with dynamic fields (material, date, type, etc.) and I'm using the "feature_number" column to sort the atlas.

It's working but I cant find the way to display 8 different entity sheets on one page so that page number 1 would contains the sheets of feature_number 1 to 8. page 2 would display feature_number 9 to 18 and so on.

We use pre-cut paper for labels and we have to print all the labels 8 by 8.

Comment: Well, what have you tried? Can you provide your current template and example data?

Comment: So far I have one label template. If I copy paste the same template on the same page, I get the same feature infos because both sheets are displaying the same "entity".

Comment: I can share my template and example data but I don't know how in here

Comment: Use a file hosting website of your chosing.

Comment: https://www.grosfichiers.com/uQT4iRBBV3v